# Detecting email using regex failed

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to detect email from clipboard using regex.

**Sample Input:**

```
sifii203@gmail.com
sifat@yahoo.com
1232@hotmail.com
```

**Code:**

```
import pyperclip,re

text = pyperclip.paste()
if text:
    agentNamesRegex = re.compile(r'\w+\d*@\w+\.\w+')
    matches = []
    print(agentNamesRegex.findall(text))
```

**Output:**(that I am getting)

```
['sifii203@gmail.com', 'sifat@yahoo.com', '1232@hotmail.com']
```

Why is `1232@hotmail.com` part of the output when I have predefined `\w+` which means at least one character will be the suffix?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know what `\w` includes? Read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: `\w` matches letters or digits or `_`. `\d*` does not have to match anything, it only matches 0+ digits.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the correction! But how would i just catch characters like a,b,c only ?

Comment: Use `[a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: thnx that works fine!